# Is this a memory leak or flood attack?

Tags: node.js

[image]

The only memory leaks I've had were gradual and only steadily increased. I would assume this was a flood, but it never goes back down. Any opinions?

Comment: uuhh, that's not enough data for us to figure out anything

Comment: @Markasoftware My general question is, can a memory leak just explode like that? I thought they were gradual?

Comment: that's kind've why it's called a leak...

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes, but from my experience they gradually grow larger and larger. They don't just appear in massive spikes like that.

Comment: What type of system is this? What type of software is being use (node packages)? What types of actions does this application handle? Is it live? What are the number of users currently? What other supporting data to do you have, and/or what is this graph about? Looks like we can confirm that memory usage grew : )